# Should idle threads be left around in long running process?

Tags: multithreading, go, daemon

I am creating a go program that is intended to run long term and listen for work. When it receives a request, it runs the work on a process queue.

I am new to golang and systems programming, so my question is this: should I spin up the process queue (with it's multiple idle worker threads) at the program launch (they will just sit there until work comes in) or should I spin them up when work arrives and shut them down when finished?

I am unclear as to the overall system impact multiple idle threads will have, but I am assuming since they are idle there will be no impact until work arrives. That being said, I want to make sure my program is a "good neighbor" and as efficient as possible.

--EDIT--

To clarify, the "process pool" is a group of worker go routines waiting for work on a channel. Should they be started/stopped when work arrives, or started when the program launches and left waiting until work comes in?

Comment: There is no such notion as "creating threads" in golang. If you are talking of goroutines; They are very cheap. Fire them up as needed.

Comment: goroutines end when their function returns. You usually don't have "idle" goroutines sitting around, they're either doing something or they've returned.

Comment: Yes, my apologize for the incorrect nomenclature, goroutines are what I'm talking about. So, having a pool of long running "idle" gorutines waiting for a message on a channel is no problem?

Comment: @SjB how do you get a pool of idle goroutines. This doesn't sound right.

Comment: Goroutines don't requires an OS thread, and have a very small stack. There's no problems having a pool waiting for messages, but because they're so cheap to spawn, a "worker pool" isn't usually the proper way to architect a program.

Comment: @TheHippo I have a dispatcher with a chan of chan. When work comes in, it is sent to the dispatcher, who distributes it to it's waiting worker goroutines.

Comment: Even if the impact is minimal it would just be bad programming imo to spin up a bunch of resources that may never actually be needed. Most applications like what you describe have a main routine that is always running which would then invoke the worker routines and listen for their completion as necessary. Why would that coordinator need to prematurely allocate resources? And as JimB pointed out above the goroutine is returning automatically unless you have something blocking in it which I think would obviously be bad.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't create a thread using standard Go library. In Go universe you should use goroutines which are so called [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).

Usually you shouldn't spawn "reusable" goroutines. They are cheap to create so create them on demand as work job arrives and finish (return from goroutine) as soon as work is completed.

Also don't hesitate to create nested goroutines. In general spawn them like crazy if you feel you should do something in **concurrent** manner and don't try to reuse them as it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a task queue pattern where there are reusable worker goroutines that wait for incoming work.The link about green threads was very helpful!

Comment: Yes, but you also said "waiting for work on a channel", so my suggestion is to write a code consuming work tasks from a channel (which is synchronous) and spawn a goroutine as work arrives instead of bothering with reusing old ones.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little cost either way. goroutines don't require a separate OS thread and consume practically no resources while blocking on a channel receive, but also cost *very* little to spin up, so there's no great reason to leave them open either.

My code rarely uses worker pools. Generally my producer will spawn a goroutine for every unit of work it produces and hands it off directly along with a response channel, then spawns a "listener" that does some formatting for the work output and pipes all the responses back to the main thread. A common pattern for me looks like:

```
func Foo(input []interface{}) resp chan interface{} {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    resp := make(chan interface{})
    listen := make(chan interface{})
    theWork := makeWork(input)
    // do work
    for _, unitOfWork := range theWork {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            // doWork has signature:
            //   func doWork(w interface{}, ch chan interface{})
            doWork(unitOfWork, listen)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    // format the output of listen chan and send to resp chan
    // then close resp chan so main can continue
    go func() {
        for r := range listen {
            resp <- doFormatting(r)
        }
        close(resp)
    }()
    // close listen chan after work is done
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(listen)
    }()
    return resp
}
```

Then my main function passes it some input and listens on the response channel

```
func main() {
    loremipsum := []string{"foo", "bar", "spam", "eggs"}
    response := Foo(loremipsum)
    for output := range response {
        fmt.Println(output)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern with tasks queue and waiting workers is common in Go. Goroutines are cheap, but order of execution is nondetermined. So if you want your system behavior to be predictable, you better would control  workers rendezvous with main routine thru unbuffered channels requested in a loop or somehow else. Otherwise some of them can be spawned but remain idle which is legal.

Comment: Thanks, this is the pattern I was going for: the work is all identical and doesn't need to be executed in a particular order